# User is created but data is not stored in Firebase realtime database

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a simple signup form. When I click signup, the user gets created but the data, such as name and email is not saved in a real-time database. I have tried and tested everything I could find online. My real-time database server is ASIA SOUTH-EAST1. And I have also changed the rules to true.
Below is my code to create user:

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                User muser= new User(name, email);
                //user is created and can be seen in authentication list
                //Code down below is to add data to database but doesnt work!     
               
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .setValue(muser)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(Signup_User.this, "Registered successfully! 
                             PLEASE LOGIN AGAIN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(Signup_User.this, 
                            Home_activity.class));
                           progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(Signup_User.this, "Something went wrong!", 
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                    }
                });

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(Signup_User.this, "Failed to register, Something went 
                 wrong!" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
              }
            }

    });
```

And the User.java file:

```
package com.example.covoid;

public class User {
    public String name, email;

    public User(){
    }
    public User(String name, String email){
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your "Toast.makeText(Signup_User.this, "Something went wrong!", 
                                         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();" displayed?

Comment: No, the progress bar spins and spins and spins nothing other than that

Comment: Is your onComplete even triggered?

Comment: Yes, the onComplete gets triggered as I can see a user being authenticated in firebase, I can log in too, but the data related to the user such as name, email doesn't get stored

Comment: How do you check that the name, email doesn't get stored?

Comment: I manually went to the firebase dashboard to check the real-time database. It shows null

Comment: So there are two onComplete methods. Are both triggered?

Comment: I guess the first onComplete doesn't get triggered, if it did it would write to the database. right>

Comment: The second (inner) one should write data to the database. So is your second (inner) else part of the if statement triggered? If you add `Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage());` do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: nothing showed up :( IDK where am going wrong

Comment: So that line of code doesn't produce any output? So is the task successful or not?

Comment: As you've discovered by now, Stack Overflow is a horribly inefficient interactive debugger. Please set breakpoints on each line of the code you shared, and then run the code in a debugger. Check the variables and logcat output on each line. Which line is the first that doesn't do what you expect it to do? Add this information to your question and the chances we can help are a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

Did you uninstall and install the app again?

That is essential for the communication with FireBase.